# How do I send a message to a discord channel when I receive a message on a RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: python, discord.py, rabbitmq

How do I send a message to a discord channel when I receive a message on a RabbitMQ queue?
So, I am making a kind of workflow automation app and I have got a discord bot for that
which basically reads a new message puts it on a rabbitMQ queue(called trigger_queue) which is then picked up by the backend
and the backend does some processing and sends back a new message on another queue(called action_queue) which is then supposed to be picked up by the bot
and send the message
Now the first part is working fine, the message gets picked up and is put on the trigger_queue
which is then used by the backend and backend puts it on the action_queue

But the message is then not being consumed on the bot side?

```py
import discord
import aiormq
import asyncio
import threading
from queueing import send_msg
class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        connection=await aiormq.connect("amqp://localhost")
        channel=await connection.channel()
        await channel.queue_declare(queue='trigger_queue')

        if message.content:
            await send_msg(channel,f'{message.author } sent {message.content}')
   
    async def send_discord_msg(self):
        async def process_message(ch,method,properties,body):
            discord_channel=await self.fetch_channel(1153970000797913112)
            if discord_channel:
                await discord_channel.send(body)
        connection=await aiormq.connect("amqp://localhost")
        channel=await connection.channel()
        await channel.queue_declare(queue='action_queue')
        await channel.basic_consume('action_queue',process_message)
    async def start(self):
        await self.send_discord_msg()
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = MyClient(intents=intents)

def run():
    loop=asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(client.start())

t=threading.Thread(target=run)
t.start()
client.run("TOKEN")
```

I was expecting that the bot would consume the messages in action_queue
and it would send a message on discord based on that message.